# Could not load type 'Project.DAL.Conext' from assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been trying to figure this one out, on and off, for a couple of days now, I have checked other answers and I can't seem to find a solution. I have provided the first half of the stack trace, but if more info is needed please let me know (didn't want this to be a 5 page post).

```
Could not load type 'eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCConext' from assembly 'eFormsRedux'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about  the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCConext' from assembly 'eFormsRedux'.

Source Error: 


Line 52:             if (ModelState.IsValid)
Line 53:             {
Line 54:                 db.RefundRequests.Add(refundRequest);
Line 55:                 db.SaveChanges();
Line 56:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

---

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCConext' from assembly 'eFormsRedux'.]
 System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) +34
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +39

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type 'eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCInitializer, eFormsRedux' for DbContext type 'eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCConext, eFormsRedux' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +236
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass6.<TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection>b__1(ContextElement e) +203
System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +164
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
```

---

I have tried a few different approaches on the web.config and I have double checked the context, probably why I'm so stumped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
 -->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DatePicker;Data Source=(local)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<contexts>
  <context type="eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCConext, eFormsRedux">
    <databaseInitializer type="eFormsRedux.DAL.FDCInitializer, eFormsRedux" />
  </context>
</contexts>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v12.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

I couldn't find anything in the Context of model classes either, but I thought I would add them just in case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using eFormsRedux.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace eFormsRedux.DAL
{
    public class FDCContext : DbContext
    {
        public FDCContext()
            : base("FDCContext")
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RefundRequest> RefundRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Supervisor> Supervisors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

      }
 }
```

---

```
namespace eFormsRedux.Models
{
    public class RefundRequest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string intAccount { get; set; }
        public string vcServiceCode { get; set; }
        public double intRefundAmount { get; set; }
        public string vcClinic { get; set; }
        public string vcName { get; set; }
        public string vcOtherName { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtDateRequested { get; set; }
        public string vcRequester { get; set; }
        public int intApproval { get; set; }
        public int intSupervisor { get; set; }
        public int intApprovedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtDateApproved { get; set; }
        public int intReturnToClinic { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your class seems to be `FDCContext` but you configured in the config file `FDCConext` (look closely - there is a typo - 't' is missing)

Comment: I will give that a shot when I get home tonight, thank you for the input.